# Meteor - Passing a jade helper into a helper function

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, pug

I'm trying to populate a list with a dataset and set the selected option with a helper function that compares the current data with another object's data (the 2 objects are linked)

I made the same type of list population with static variables:
Jade-

```
         select(name='status')
            option(value='Newly Acquired' selected='{{isCurrentState "Newly Acquired"}}') Newly Acquired
            option(value='Currently In Use' selected='{{isCurrentState "Currently In Use"}}') Currently In Use
            option(value='Not In Use' selected='{{isCurrentState "Not In Use"}}') Not In Use
            option(value='In Storage' selected='{{isCurrentState "In Storage"}}') In Storage
```

Coffeescript-

```
  "isCurrentState" : (state) ->
     return @status == state
```

This uses a helper isCurrentState to match a given parameter to the same object that my other code is linked to so I know that part works

The code I'm trying to get to work is :
Jade-

```
            select.loca(name='location')
               each locations
                   option(value='#{siteName}' selected='{{isCurrentLocation {{siteName}} }}') #{siteName}
```

Coffeescript-

```
  "isCurrentLocation": (location) ->
     return @locate == location
```

All the other parts are functioning 100%, but the selected part is not

I've also tried changing the way I entered the selected='' part in a manner of ways such as:

- selected='{{isCurrentLocation "#{siteName}" }}'
- selected='{{isCurrentLocation "#{siteName} }}'
- selected='{{isCurrentLocation {{siteName}} }}'
- selected='#{isCurrentLocation "{{siteName}}" }'
- selected='#{isCurrentLocation {{siteName}} }'
- selected='#{isCurrentLocation #{siteName} }'

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
Is there a better way of achieving this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:
Thanks [@david-weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon) for the quick reply, i've tried this out a bit and realised that I wasn't exactly clear in what I was trying to accomplish in my question.
I have a template "update_building" created with a parameter( a buidling object) with a number of attributes, one of which is "locate".

Locations is another object with a number of attributes as well, one of which is "siteName". One of the siteName == locate and thus i need to pass in the siteName from locations to match it to the current building's locate attribute

Though it doesn't work in the context I want to use it definitely pointed me in a direction I didn't think of. I am looking into moving the parent template(The building) date context as a parameter into the locations template and using it from within the locations template. This is easily fixable in normal HTML spacebars with:

`{{>locations parentDataContext/variable}}`

Something like that in jade would easily solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the datacontexts some more and ended up making the options that populate the select into a different template and giving that template a helper, accessing the template's parent's data context and using that to determine which location the building had saved in it so that I could set that option to selected

Jade-

```
template(name="location_building_option")
   option(value='#{siteName}' selected='{{isSelected}}') #{siteName}
```

Coffeescript -

```
Template.location_building_option.helpers
   'isSelected': ->
      parent = Template.parentData(1)
      buildSite = parent.locate
      return @siteName == buildSite
```

Thanks [@david-weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon), Your answer helped me immensely to head in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

```
selected='{{isCurrentLocation siteName}}'
```

### Long answer

You don't really need to pass the current location because the helper should know it's own context. Here's a simple (tested) example:

**jade**

```
template(name='myTemplate')
  select.location(name='location')
    each locations
      option(value=this selected=isCurrentLocation) #{this}
```

**coffee**

```
LOCATIONS = [
  'Newly Acquired'
  'Currently In Use'
  'Not In Use'
  'In Storage'
]

Template.myTemplate.helpers
  locations: LOCATIONS

  isCurrentLocation: ->
    @toString() is Template.instance().location.get()

Template.myTemplate.onCreated ->
  @location = new ReactiveVar LOCATIONS[1]
```